# converting my long statement into list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Currently I have a statement like this that works great:

```
if (l['key'] != "0") and (l['key'] != "") and (l['key'] != 'm3u8') and ('HIT' not in k['key']) :
```

im new to list comprehension so instead of adding (l['key'] != "something") each time I want to exclude extension I tried to do this:

```
ext_group=["",'m3u8','0']
url_strings =['m3u8','test1','0','gif','potato']

if any(ext not in url_strings for ext in ext_group):
```

but this isn't working. normally in a loop I can just say "print ext" but in this case it'll error saying I havent defined it. If I try to print out the url_strings it prints out the full list instead of just the items that have not been filtered out.

What did I do wrong here or what am I not understanding?

EDIT tried to do this but its also not filtering, by not filtering I mean I still see "",'m3u8','0' values printed out l['key']

```
for ext in ext_group:
     if (l['key']!= ext) and ('HIT' not in k['key']) :
         print l['key']
```

Comment: If you want to do something for every `ext` that matches, you can't use `any` for that. The whole point of `any` is that you throw away all information except whether there was any match. If you don't want to do that, write what you _do_ want. For example, `(ext for ext in ext_group if ext not in url_strings)` gives you an iterable of all matches, instead of just whether there was one or not. And if you put that in square brackets instead of parens, you get a list of all matches.

Comment: I’ll work on an answer, but essentially the scope of `ext` is only within `any()` which returns a Bool. With your current setup, it will return `true` if one or more strings in `ext_group` are not in `url_strings`. Is this what you intend?

Comment: Meanwhile, comprehensions are useful when the only thing you want to do inside a loop is gather, filter, or transform some values into the output. If you're looping for side effects, like a `print`, rather than to gather some output, don't use a comprehension, just use a `for` statement.

Comment: @abarnert What I want to do is only print out (or continue processing) `l['key']` only if the value of `l['key']`  does not equal any of the values in ext_group if taht makes sense

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you are trying to filter out a JSON object from keys if the value is anything around `['','m3u8','0']` and another JSON object which has value for 'key' as a list and the list is not supposed to have `'HIT'` as an element.

What you have tried in your list comprehension is almost correct but there was an error in the understanding of list comprehension.

Consider the below code:

```
ext_group=["",'m3u8','0']
url_strings =['m3u8','test1','0','gif','potato']

proper_values = []
for ext in url_strings:
    if ext not in ext_group:
        proper_values.append(ext)
```

This is what you are intended to do in the list comprehension, but you have switched the lists which has to be iterated in `for loop` and to be checked for `if` condition.

Instead of

```
if any(ext not in url_strings for ext in ext_group)
```

you should have gone with

```
if any ([ext for ext in url_strings if ext not in ext_group])
```

You can add your second condition in the same check also. Something like,

```
if any([i for i in url_strings if i not in ext_group]) and ('HIT' not in k['key']):
```

Hope you have got what were you looking for. Else post your questions as comments.